# upload file through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use 2 file index.js, upload.php try to upload file(img) through ajax and if success append to div `uploadfile_show`.
but it doesn't work , have few question and below is my code any suggestion?

Thanks.

upload.php
1. `form enctype` still need to add?
2. `if($_FILES)` and check $_FILES size or tmp_name still use `$_FILES`?

```
if($_FILES){
    $filename = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
    $filetmp = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['uploadfile']['size'];
    if($filesize < 1000000){
        move_uploaded_file($filetmp,'upload/tmp/'.$filename);
        print"
            upload success
            <img src=\"upload/tmp/$filename\">
        ";
    }
    else{
    }
}
else{
    print"
        <div class=\"uploaddiv\">
            <form enctype=\"multipart/form_data\">
                <input type=\"type\" name=\"uploadfile\">
                <input type=\"submit\" value=\"upload\" class=\"btn\">
            </form>
        </div>
    ";
}
print"
    <div class=\"uploadfile_show\"></div>
";
```

index.js
3. this few line is it the right?
`var uf = $('.uploaddiv form');var fd = new FormData(uf);fd.append('uploadfile', uploadfile);`
`data: fd,`
4. any thing I missed or wrong?

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var uf = $('.uploaddiv form');
    var fd = new FormData(uf);
    fd.append('uploadfile', uploadfile);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        data: fd,
        processData:false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(html){
            $('.uploadfile_show').append(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: FormData is only working on recent browsers - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData. Have you checked your browser version?

Comment: @Sithu yes my browser is safari 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormData` takes a form element in its constructor not a jQuery object, also as you are using ajax to submit the form you'll have to prevent its default action(i.e. submitting) by calling `preventDefault()`

```
$('.btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var uf = $('.uploaddiv form');
    var fd = new FormData(uf[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        data: fd,
        processData:false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(html){
            $('.uploadfile_show').append(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @user1775888 you're missing a `/` here `'upload/tmp'.$filename`, `'upload/tmp/'.$filename` also you might want to use `basename`, `$filename = basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);`

Comment: but after I click btn, the url will change like this `index.php? uploadfile=` and not show anything..

Comment: @user1775888 sorry i thought the button was outside the form. See update