# Get File from File Path and Upload - Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have an output of

```
C:/Path/file/file.mp3
```

now I need to fetch the file from the path and upload using jquery

and store that file to 'audioData' variable...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'URL',
    data: {
        image: imageData,
        audio: audioData
    }
    // etc
});
```

How can I get in php? as a FILE or POST ?

Answer (score -1):

Ajax what not supposed to be used to upload file, that's form with multipart type job.
However some browser are now supporting it, but not all of them, this works nice check a look:http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/

Comment: Another technique that will work on older browser it to create a form as normal but have jquery post it to a hidden iframe.

Comment: is there any way i can assign value of Path to <input type="file"> ?

Answer (score -1):

Post file through ajax and form? That could happen, see [upload file through ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495296/upload-file-through-ajax)

Post file through ajax without form?　I dont think so.